# how to display my current ip address using php

Tags: php

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

echo "$ip";
```

currently I am using this above code for displaying IP address but it's showing my localhost address please help me to know my internet IP address

Comment: What do you mean by `my current ip`? Client/Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: my internet ip address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/55790/2025923 may help you, see the code

Comment: actually i am trying to open my website for particular ip address. i mean only for my internet ip address

Answer (score 0):

getenv() is used to get the value of an environment variable in PHP.

// Function to get the client IP address

```
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
```

}